# how to remove nginx modules?Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan

Tags: nginx

Hi I have something problem with nginx. When I get restarted nginx I take this error in log and nginx does not start. Only recently i have encountered an error something below.

ON log file `/var/log/nginx/error.log`

`[info]: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:71`

I don't think i would need nchan module for a simple wordpress site. I'm using ubuntu OS. My question is how do i remove nchan module?

Answer (score 2):

On Debian derivatives the directory `/etc/nginx/modules-enabled` contains the configuration files used to load modules (or better symbolic links to the configuration files). You just need to delete the appropriate file and reload nginx:

```
systemctl reload nginx
```